# GDB can't load dll

Tags: dll, gdb

I am running windows 7 x64.  I recently just set up mingw and gdb on my system.  While it appears the debugger works every time I load a app into it I get the following error.

Error: dll starting at 0x771c0000 not found.

Anyone know what is up with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but does GDB know about ASLR?

Comment: I have no idea at all.  If it does not know about ASLR that could be the issue.  From my research it seems this Error only comes up on 64 bit.

Comment: You can use the Windows Driver Kit linker with the "/edit" option to modify PE flags without rebuilding the file.  PE Explorer will also do that: http://www.heaventools.com/PE_Explorer_section_editor.htm

Comment: Because if GDB didn't understand ASLR, it'd look for a DLL at the original base address, then wouldn't find it because ASLR would've moved it. 

Like I said, it's a shot in the dark - I'd ask the mingw mailing list for a better answer though.